# Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'dynamic sql query' to data type int

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure for checking if row exist. I use this with ADO.NET for a dynamic query instead of having similar queries for all my tables.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Row_Exist]    
    @TableName VARCHAR(50),
    @ColumnName VARCHAR(50),
    @RowId INT
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

    SET @sqlQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(1) as count FROM  ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' = ' + @RowId

    EXEC(@sqlQuery)
END
```

If I execute this with a valid rowid, tablename, and columnname, I get the following error

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value `SELECT COUNT(1) as count FROM  Users WHERE UserID =`  to data type int.

Comment: That is lucky for you. The reason it fails is because @RowID is an int and you don't cast it to a string datatype. As such it attempts to convert all these elements to an int and fails. The reason I say you are lucky is because this code is wide open to sql injection. See this link. http://bobby-tables.com/ But...why do you need a procedure to count rows in all your tables anyway? Seems like something is off here.

Comment: Well thank you for the heads up about sql injection, I would consider that. but I am only give this procedure data from inside my code, I am not excepting any data from outside such as a form, its just that I feel instead of having 10 queries to check if row exist in different tables, I would rather have only one procedure

Comment: @SaadA it's much easier to debug code when calling Stored Procedures named dbo.DoesUserExist, dbo.DoesCustomerExist, etc. than debugging code that goes to a generic function that builds strings of SQL. More numerous, concise SPs don't cost more rent.

Comment: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Answer (score 2):

This is because you try to concate int to varchar. Please try the below sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Row_Exist]    
    @TableName varchar(50),
    @ColumnName varchar(50),
    @RowId int
AS 
BEGIN 
 DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''

  SET @sqlQuery = 'SELECT COUNT(1) as count FROM  ' + @TableName + ' WHERE ' + @ColumnName + ' = ' + CAST(@RowId AS VARCHAR(20))

 EXEC(@sqlQuery)
END
```

Answer (score 0):

Use parameters where you can.  I tend to use `REPLACE()` to fill in the other values:

```
DECLARE @sqlQuery NVARCHAR(MAX) = '
SELECT COUNT(1) as count
FROM @TableName
WHERE @ColumnName = @RowId
';
SET @sqlQuery = REPLACE(REPLACE(@sqlQuery, '@TableName', quotename(@TableName)), '@ColumnName', quotename(@ColumnName));

EXEC sp_executesql @sqlQuery, N'@RowId int', @RowId=@RowId;
```

Comment: Really should wrap the table name in quotename to help minimize the possibility of sql injection.